# django imagefield

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте. Есть модель Film:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

И есть темплейт, в котором имеется следующая строчка:

```
 <img class="card-img-top" src={{ x.cover }}>
```

Но при запуске сервера, он ругается на "GET /covers/326.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2076.
Возможно, я делаю что-то не так, и src, скорее всего, в таком виде вообще указывать нельзя. Но я не понимаю, в чем проблема

Answer (score 2):

`<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ x.cover.url }}">`